# Scroll not shown in list created by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a html box with list ul:

```
<div id="profile_photo_conteiner">
                <ul>

     </ul>
 </div>
```

in this list I add some pictures with jquery:

```
...
   var i =1;
    var num = 10;
    while (i <= num)
        {
                        $( "#profile_photo_conteiner ul" ).append("\
                        <li>\
                            <img src=\"\"/>\
                            <div class=\"gallery_image_title\">\
                                <h5 class=\"gallery_title\">Click me</h5>\
                            </div>\
             </li>\
                    ");
```

Everything is shown but I didn't get scroll by x axis. I tried a lot variations, and figured out that if I delete ul and li and just add pictures the scroll is shown, but as soon I try with ul it is don't show up. [jsfiddle - code](https://jsfiddle.net/cxz0n2u2/1/) - here is my code for some tests. So is there an option for list ul to sroll them?
Part of  css:

```
#profile_photo_conteiner {
height: 210px;
padding-top: 10px;
overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
width: 200x;
white-space:nowrap;
margin-bottom: 55px;
border: solid 1px red;

}

/*-galery*//*
#profile_photo_conteiner ul {
  overflow-x:scroll;
  overflow-y:hidden;

}*/


#profile_photo_conteiner ul li{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    position:relative;
    cursor: pointer;


}

#profile_photo_conteiner ul li img {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

So I delete the jquery code, since the problem is not in it
OK so here it is [content](https://jsfiddle.net/97ngsa7g/) - it is the same code but with height over 1000 px to show that we have enough content,
[content -2](https://jsfiddle.net/cxz0n2u2/9/) - agin the same code but with a normal height so we have anogh content oveflow-y is hidden and you don't see the rest of result, overflow-x doesn't show up (if I put overflow-x scroll) scroll will show up but it will not work since content don't go by x axis.

Comment: do you mean horizontal or vertical scroll?

Comment: I need horizontal, x axis, not vertical (that one is some how works fine lol)

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it seems that you are hiding the vertical scrollbar through css:

`overflow-y: hidden;`

this should be

`overflow-y: auto;`

You can then hide the horizontal scroll by doing the opposite for `overflow-x`

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cxz0n2u2/3/)

Comment: Your content is probably not yet wide enough for the bar to appear.

Comment: Set the `max-width:` on the container and it should show the bar as the content becomes wider than the container

Comment: again it is not going to work the width is 200px , and it doesn't matter, jquery has a while that repeat 10 time. So in result we have 10 pictures and they are there (simple test put height: 1000px and you will see it) . You don't see the rest content since overflow-y is hidden.

Comment: the fiddle doesn't quite represent your problem as there are no pictures, can you update the fiddle to be more accurate of your situation?

Comment: I edited my post put codes,so check, they must to show you what is not working. Problem is that content ignore the float left by x axis

Comment: Actually, your selector is wrong, that's why your CSS doesn't work. You can check out the revision 13 that edited, to see that it's now effected

Answer (score 0):

As the content is not yet overflow, so you cannot see the horizontal scroll (x-axis) like you meant/wanted it to be. 
You can try to trigger this by setting the max-width of the container smaller than the content.

```
max-width: certain-px-smaller-than-content;
```

Incase you want to show the vertical scroll, you can set

```
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Comment: you are not write jsfiddle.net there is 10 images but it show only 2 since the rest is under it and overflow-y is hidden so there is enoght content and you variant will not work... For simple test in jsfiddle.net chnge the height to 1000px and you will see all the images that was hidden

Comment: Well then I don't know why you want to see the horizontal scroll?
Besides, I can't see the image.
In that case, I added the max-height to the container, so you can limit the number of items you want to show ;)
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cxz0n2u2/12/)

Comment: so you now see the problem that vertical scroll doesn't work, and I need the horizontal scroll since it is suppose to be there. And I want to know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mean like this one? [JSFiddle revision 13](https://jsfiddle.net/cxz0n2u2/13/)

Comment: well it is vertical, but I need Horizontal, x axis, from left to right, from one side to another, parallel to  ---------,  y=b where b is any number....

Comment: Hope this is what you want [JSFiddle revision 14](https://jsfiddle.net/cxz0n2u2/14/)

Comment: yes it is, i just change div to li, but it still work, can you explain why? just to know in future, and post you respond, taht I can mark it as correct one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105653/discussion-between-toan-lu-and-alex-mike).